# Application closes after Crystal Report Viewer Print dialog is Canceled

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am afraid I have no idea where to even START with regard to giving anything remotely like "code samples". So all I can do is describe the problem in the hope that this rings a bell with someone....

The situation is as follows. We have an WPF assembly with a WPF window in it hosting a Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer control

```
xmlns:Viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
```

Everything is working just fine except for one utterly baffling issue. The user goes and launches the functionality that shows them this Window, and the report runs fine showing the Preview of the report.

The user then proceeds to click on the PRINT button (shown as the top left icon in the Viewer) which brings up the Print Dialog - you know the one, where the user picks what printer to send the output to. But at that point the user changes their mind and clicks Cancel

All good, right? It just closes the Print dialog, and I am once again looking at the WPF window that contains the Report Preview. But now comes the crazy bit. When I CLOSE that window, the entire application closes.

I am stepping through the code to see what is happening, and I am in the Closed event handler for that Window

```
Private Sub CRReport_viewer_Closed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Closed
```

I can step through it to the very end, and nothing untoward happens. Everything is perfectly fine, I get to the End Sub, I hit F8 one more time.... and I'm in the Application.Exit event of the main program. I see no code anywhere invoking a .Close, .Exit, .Quit, .Kill, .Shutdown .... NOTHING that would suggest to me that anything has instructed the application to close down. It just does. No Unexpected Error, nothing. It's like it's decided that the user has hit the X button and it must close now, everything by the book.

I do notice ONE odd thing in the Closed handler. When I Preview the Report and I hit the X Button on that dialog, when I step through the code I look at

```
application.Current.MainWindow
```

And as I expected, it's the main window of the main application. After I show the Print dialog and hit Cancel, and THEN I close that window however....

```
application.Current.MainWindow
```

is Nothing.

```
Application.Current.IsShuttingDown
```

= True. And so on.

However - the same Main Window that I found checking for application.Current.MainWindow **without** showing and canceling the Print dialog is still present in the

```
Application.Current.Windows
```

Collection. I can even go to the Immediate Window and do

```
application.Current.MainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.item(0)
```

and

```
Application.Current.IsShuttingDown = False
```

at the End Sub. But still, when I hit that F8 button, the next step is exit the application.

So all I can ask is....

**Has anybody got a clue as to what might possibly be going on here**

and

**Is there away to stop this behaviour?**

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

RIGHT ... I found out what the problem was.

I think it is related to an issue described in
"Pro WPF 4.5 in VB: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5" - an EBook by Matthew MacDonald - Chapter 29 (Page 924) - read the part about "One potential problem is the way the PrintDialog class works with Modal Windows"

The bit that stands out is the part where he says "The somewhat clumsy solution is to manually change your application's main window to the current window before you call PrintDialog.ShowDialog() and then switch it back immediately afterward". It seems fairly obvious to me that this is exactly what SAP decided to do in their ReportViewer, and that their logic is faulty in the sense that "switch it back immediately afterward" is not happening when the user hits Cancel on the Print Dialog. Tsk!

The solution presented itself when, instead of looking at the Closed event handler, I looked at the Closing event handler.

When we show the dialog, in the New() method of the WPF Window the Application.Current.MainWindow is still set - correctly - to the calling application's Main Window. When the user simply runs the Report and closes the window, and you go into the Closing event handler, it is still - correctly - set to the same window. The same is true if the user chooses to Print and **goes ahead** with the Printing.

But when the user **Cancels** out of the Print Dialog, and then they close the WPF Dialog, in the Closing event I observed that now Application.Current.Mainwindow is set to that Dialog, NOT to the correct Main Window of the application.

That ties in perfectly with my suspicion that they fail to "switch it back" when the user hits Cancel. So I had to do it instead.

So when the New() method is invoked I establish what the MainWindow is and store it in a module level object variable. And then in the Closing Event Handler, if the MainWindow has changed I change it back.

And that sorted the problem

**sigh**

Comment: https://books.google.ie/books?id=DwPC71448KEC&pg=PA924&lpg=PA924&dq=print+dialog+cancel+changes+mainwindow&source=bl&ots=QQ1ng8ALML&sig=ACfU3U2ir6liahuOCW4VGPCPO5ebP5v01A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd79HG07HkAhXsRxUIHWa9DrgQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=print%20dialog%20cancel%20changes%20mainwindow&f=false